# Discrepancy between Member.Count results and Actual users in Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

More than a problem is a doubt. I've come across a discrepancy I'm trying to understand.
I ran a member count for a few groups in my domain, but when actually exported the users for a manual review I noticed some of the values I had previously obtained weren't "exactly right".

For example: I ran the following PS line: (Get-ADGroup  -Properties *).Member.Count

This is the result I got (image below):
[image]

To my surprise when I exported that same group to a CSV file, found out it actually has 1800 user accounts in it.

Does anyone know what's going on? of if there is a way, I can get the correct count so I'm not sharing incorrect information without having to do the manual export and review?

UPDATE: - The code I use to view member count from specific groups I add in a text file is this:

```
$groups = Get-Content 'C:\Users\File.txt'
Foreach($group in $groups) {
    (Get-ADGroup -Identity $group -Properties *) | Select-Object @{Expression = { $group }; Label = 'Grup Name' }, @{Label = 'Users in Group'; Expression = { ($_.Member.Count) } }
}
```

The export is a regular export to a file:

```
$groups = Get-Content 'c:\Users\File.txt'
foreach($Group in $Groups) {
    Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group -Recursive | 
        Get-ADUser -Properties Mail | 
        Select-Object @{Expression = { $Group }; Label = 'Group Name' }, Name, Mail, Samaccountname | 
        Export-Csv 'c:\Users\Export.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Append 
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How could we know what is wrong without seeing your code?

Comment: Hello @SantiagoSquarzon the code I use to veiw member count from specific groups i add in a text file is this:

$groups = Get-Content "C:\Users\File.txt"
Foreach($group in $groups) {(Get-ADGroup -Identity $group -Properties *) | Select @{Expression={$group};Label="Grup Name"},@{Label="Users in Group";Expression={($_.Member.Count)}}}

Comment: please add the code to your question instead of the comment section

Comment: you're using `-Recursive` on the second snipped. That by itself should explain the problem.

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoSquarzon. I have [-Recursive] because there are groups as members of groups, and without it those weren't showing up. Didn't realize it was gathering all those other extra users. Is there another way to get that extract without [-Recursive] affecting the overall number of users in the group?

Comment: I dont understand. Just remove `-Recursive` if you dont want to have the count of nested members

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a group called `GroupA` that has these members:

```
User1
User2
GroupB
```

And `GroupB` has these members:

```
User3
User4
User5
```

The result of `(Get-ADGroup GroupA -Properties *).Member` will list the members without caring what type of object the member is. So the count will be 3. `GroupB` counts as 1 member.

Now if you use `Get-ADGroupMember GroupA -Recursive`, it will not count `GroupB` as a member, but instead look inside `GroupB` and return all the objects that are not groups. So the list it returns will be:

```
User1
User2
User3
User4
User5
```

If `GroupB` had any groups inside, those would expanded too, all the way until it finds a group that doesn't not have any groups as a member.

So you have to decide which count you want.

As a side note, it's wise when using the `-Properties` parameter to only include the properties you intend to use. Using `*` will slow it down for no reason. So you're better off using `-Properties Member` if that's the only property you're going to use.